# How do I resolve <StoreStateProvider> error in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

I cloned a gatsby application and when running the development server:

```
$ gatsby develop
```

I received a  error:

> ```
> The above error occurred in the <StoreStateProvider> component:
>     in StoreStateProvider
>     in App
> ```

```
React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, App.


 ERROR

Warning: App: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI.


 ERROR

UNHANDLED REJECTION Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app




  Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for o  ne of the following reasons:
  1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
  2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
  3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
  See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

  - react.development.js:1465 resolveDispatcher
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[gatsby]/[gatsby-cli]/[react]/cjs/react.development.js:1465:13

  - react.development.js:1496 useState
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[gatsby]/[gatsby-cli]/[react]/cjs/react.development.js:1496:20

  - context.js:17 StoreStateProvider
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[gatsby]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/reporter/loggers/ink/context.js:17:41

  - react-reconciler.development.js:6036 renderWithHooks
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:6036:18

  - react-reconciler.development.js:8570 mountIndeterminateComponent
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:8570:13

  - react-reconciler.development.js:9938 beginWork$1
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:9938:16

  - react-reconciler.development.js:11563 Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:11563:10

  - react-reconciler.development.js:11740 invokeGuardedCallback
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:11740:31

  - react-reconciler.development.js:15778 beginWork$$1
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:15778:7

  - react-reconciler.development.js:14696 performUnitOfWork
    [New-webelight-gatsby]/[react-reconciler]/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:14696:12


E:\Webelight\New-webelight-gatsby>
```

Comment: for risk of this Q being deleted - i wanted to add:
it looks like its an on-going issue - however it seems by 1 - removing node_modules and reinstalling may help, and 2. its causes by mismatch of react versions in the app itself
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19827

Answer (score 7):

**Update**:
It seems that upgrading Gatsby to `2.23.11` may have resolved this, however I haven't tested myself. [comment](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19827#issuecomment-649885137)

**Oct 2020**: Issue still persists in `2.24.66`

---

This seems to be an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19827) [as of May 2020]

The issue comes down to a mismatch of `React` and the underlying `gatsby` version that may have been previously installed in the application.

Having a React version lower than `16.8.0` seems to cause this issue, while `gatsby@2.19.18` tries to limit the effect on this - it does appear it hasn't been fully merged as a PR - [source](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19827#issuecomment-587108239)

A simple method is to

1. remove the `node_modules` directory
2. remove `package-lock.json`
3. `npm i`

An alternative could be to use `npm update`, but the comments in that issue has had results

Comment: I'm using Gatsby 2.24.66 and still getting this issue when trying to run "gatsby develop". Been troubleshooting for hours.